# Why can't I use my reactor terminal in space engineers?

Tags: space-engineers

I am looking right at my reactor terminal in survival mode however when I press K it opens up my inventory and I cant put uranium in the reactor (I am using a small reactor on a small ship). My friend has the same problem but it works fine on a large ship.

Comment: Did you place the reactor? By default if someone places a block, they are the owner of that block and the option to share inventory is disabled.

Answer (score 4):

The small reactor has only one opening which can be used to access its inventory. At first glance the side with the opening can be mistaken for a base it is supposed to stand on. Make sure you build your reactor oriented in a way that the side with the opening is accessible (or connected to a conveyor system powered by an already running generator and connected to a storage container containing uranium ingots).

Answer (score -1):

Make sure hints are turned on and then mouse over the yellow port, which is on one of the sides. It should give a hint on how to open it. If it doesn't, your pointer is in the wrong place, or it's not a reactor.

Comment: The small reactor on a small ship can only be accessed from one direction.